# Xcode threw up "changing property maskToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

everyone. In order to create a iOS app, I'm using OS X (version 10.11.1), Xcode (version 7.1) and PhoneGap (v5.3.6).

And then, I wrote a simple programs -- index.html and rkBLE.js

Here is `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="rkBLE.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center style="margin-top: 150px;">
            <form name="hoge" action="#">
                <input type="button" name="hoge" value="Bluetooth button" onclick="return rkBLE();" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, here is `rkBLE.js`.

```
function rkBLE()
{
    if(confirm("Rirei Kuroshima"))
        return false;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I connected Mac with iPad Mini, and pressed run/build button to install the app into the iPad.

App is launched, and I pressed "Bluetooth button". However, popup event did NOT occur. If somebody knows "What is wrong", please tell me the reason.

Xcode threw up the following messages:

```
2015-11-09 16:46:37.619 Hello World[549:107470] <CATransformLayer: 0x12f566dd0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-11-09 16:46:37.619 Hello World[549:107470] <CATransformLayer: 0x12f5cefd0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-11-09 16:46:37.620 Hello World[549:107470] <CATransformLayer: 0x12f5780e0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

Comment: `<meta>` tags, which are automatically generated by PhoneGap, seem to do bad things. JavaScript woks after deleting all meta tags.

Comment: you should learn how to configure the Content-Security-Policy meta tag instead of deleting it, and you shouldn't use inline javascript

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a beginner of HTML/JS/CSS. Although I thought that it's NOT good to delete meta tags, I didn't know what to do. So, I deleted all meta tags. I take this opportunity to learn HTML/JS/CSS more. Thanks.